# How to protect custom endpoints using BasicAuth?

Tags: python, eve

Say I have enabled authentication to the resources using BasicAuth:

```
class MyBasicAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self,username,password,allowed_roles,resource,method):
        return username == 'secretusername' and password == 'secretpass'
```

I also have custom routes which are used to manage documents from a HTML view. How do I use the same MyBasicAuth to protect the all the custom routes? I also need to implement logic which authenticates using the above MyBasicAuth.
Please help me with this. It's for personal use, so I preferred hard coding the username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the `requires_auth` decorator which is used internally by Eve itself. That way, your auth class will also be used to protect your custom routes:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import requires_auth

app = Eve()

@app.route('/hello')
@requires_auth('resource')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank u. I fixed it with session authentication. I'll try this too... thank u.

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure to mark it as Solved if it works for you, so others can spot this solution amongst others.

Comment: oh, that's much simpler @NicolaIarocci! It should be available in eve docs.

Comment: @gcw it's basic flask stuff, not eve, although I agree that requires_auth is in fact a eve artefact :) I have a blog post about it on my site. Should probably go in the Snippets section of the docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use a custom end-point Authentication you will find it difficult as mentioned here:
https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/860
I ended up writing a wrapper to get around the issue of 'resource' not being passed to 'requires_auth':

```
def auth_resource(resource):
def fdec(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(resource=resource, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
return fdec
```

This way you can define in your DOMAIN an authentication class:

```
DOMAIN = {
    'testendpoint'= {'authentication':MyCustomAuthetication},
    'otherendpoints'=...
```

And in my app I have wrapped the requires_auth decorator and added this as a authentication resource.

```
@app.route('/testendpoint/<item>', methods=['GET'])
@auth_resource('testendpoint')
@requires_auth('item')
def my_end_point_function(*args, **kwargs):
    dosomthinghere
```

As long as an authentication class is defined in the settings file for an endpoint, this also allows you to reuse any authentication defined in another endpoint which may be handy if you want to make sure all the endpoints use the same authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flask blueprints for your custom routes, you can add a before request function for your blueprint to do that.

First, create a function to check authentication from blueprints. You need to get the `Authorization` header from the flask request by yourself, like this:

```
from flask import request, abort, current_app
from werkzeug.http import parse_authorization_header

def check_blueprint_auth():
    if 'Authorization' not in request.headers:
        print('Authorization header not found for authentication')
        return abort(401, 'Authorization header not found for authentication')
    header = parse_authorization_header(request.headers['Authorization'])
    username = None if header is None else header['username']
    password = None if header is None else header['password']

    return username == 'secretusername' and password == 'secretpass'
```

Then, you can set this function to be called before each blueprint's request. Below is an example of a blueprint definition, setting the `before_request` function:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app as app
# your auth function
from auth import check_blueprint_auth

blueprint = Blueprint('prefix_uri', __name__)

# this sets the auth function to be called
blueprint.before_request(check_blueprint_auth)


@blueprint.route('/custom_route/<some_value>', methods=['POST'])
def post_something(some_value):
#  something
```

Finally, you need to bind the blueprint with your `eve` app. An example on how to bind blueprints, taken in part from [here](http://python-eve.org/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html):

```
from eve import Eve
# your blueprint
from users import blueprint
from flask import current_app, request

app = Eve()
# register the blueprint to the main Eve application
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

app.run()
```

Hope that helps.