# How do we use python-eve @requires_auth decorator on custom endpoints?

Tags: python, eve

Following the examples from Nicola https://nicolaiarocci.com/building-custom-endpoint-handlers-with-eve/ regarding requires_auth decorator, I cannot get it to work as intended and I need some help.

Essentially, it appears to work for the default authentication method, but I need it to work with my custom authentication class.

in `settings.py` I have defined a resource..

```
my = {
    'schema': {
        'test': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
    },
    'authentication': clientAuth,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
}

DOMAIN = {
            'my': my,
          }
```

Then I have defined the `clientAuth` class like this..

```
class clientAuth(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        clients = app.data.driver.db['clients']
        lookup = {'token': token}
        if allowed_roles:
            lookup['roles'] = {'$in': allowed_roles}
        client = clients.find_one(lookup)
        if client:

            slug = client['slug']
            add_db_to_config(app, slug)
            self.set_mongo_prefix(slug)
        return client
```

my custom endpoint looks like this..

```
@app.route('/test')
@requires_auth("my")
def my():
    # stuff
```

I expect (maybe wrongfully) that the argument `my` in the `requires_auth` decorator should utilize the authentication method defined in the `my` domain?

If I am wrong, how do I use custom authentication classes in my custom endpoints?

Thanks!

See [How to protect custom endpoints using BasicAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160290/how-to-protect-custom-endpoints-using-basicauth)

https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/860