# Python-Eve: Custom behaviour on PUT request

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I am using PyEve and plan to use it for my MongoDB database API. I also have a message broker running alongside the database, and I'd like to use the eve framework for both. How can I implement custom behavior in eve so that a PUT request does not update the database, but instead sends the request data to my message broker?

I am aware that I could add some flask code in `run.py` (like below), but this bypasses eve authentication and is thus unsuitable:

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!') # pretend the message broker is reading from stdout
```

I have also looked at [event hooks](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#eventhooks), but I'm not sure that they can do what I want.

UPDATE: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160290/how-to-protect-custom-endpoints-using-basicauth) explains how to add auth to a custom endpoint, but ideally I'd like to add to an existing (eve-generated) endpoint rather than create an entirely new one.

```
/hello  # custom endpoint, undesirable
/people/hello?where{"lastname"="Punzi"} # attached to existing endpoint
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134383/servicing-html-requests-with-eve/) indicates that I can achieve the desired functionality using a blueprint or the standard flask app.route() function. This question should thus be closed as a duplicate.

For posterity, a minimal solution which includes auth and builds on top of an existing eve endpoint is shown below:

```
# /people is an existing eve endpoint
@app.route('/people/hello/', methods = ['GET', 'PUT'])
@app.route('/people/<string:lastname>/hello/', methods = ['GET', 'PUT'])
# @requires_auth('resource')
def rings(lastname=''):
    # send PUT data out to broker
    return "Hello {lastname}!".format(lastname=lastname)
```

Comment: Closing as a duplicate: [Servicing html requests with Eve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134383/servicing-html-requests-with-eve)